# Difference between 'add' and 'adds' in ARM assembler?

Tags: arm, gas

I am starting to look a bit more precisely at ARM assembler and I looked up some dumps from `objdump`. I saw a lot of instruction (`add` is not the only one) with an extra `s` at the end (`adds`, `subs`, ...).

I looked a bit to the ARM documentation and it seems to mean something significant, but I can't figure out exactly what (the documentation I found about it seemed extremely obscure to me).

Has somebody some insight on what is the meaning of this extra `s` added at the end of some ARM instructions ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Usual `ADD` doesn't update flags.
`ADDS` does.
See better documentation at [arm infocenter](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0489i/Cihcjfjg.html).
As it wrote there:

> If S is specified, these instructions update the N, Z, C and V flags according to the result.

Comment: @perror If you want another concrete example, consider a loop `while(--i){...}`. One way to implement it is to have `sub reg, #1` followed by an explicit compare to zero (which will set the `Z` zero flag when reg becomes 0), then a predicated branch. With `subs reg, #1` the `Z` flag is implicitly updated, therefore no explicit comparison is required.

Answer (score 13):

The extra `s` character added to the ARM instruction mean that the **APSR** (Application Processor Status Register) will be updated depending on the outcome of the instruction.

The status register (APSR) contain four flags `N`, `Z`, `C` and `V` which means the following:

- `N == 0`: The result is greater or equal to 0, which is considered positive, and so the `N` (negative) bit is set to 0.
- `Z == 1`: The result is 0, so the `Z` (zero) bit is set to 1.
- `C == 1`: We lost some data because the result did not fit into 32 bits, so the processor indicates this by setting `C` (carry) to 1.
- `V = 0`: From a two's complement signed-arithmetic viewpoint, 0xffffffff really means -1, so the operation we did was really (-1) + 1 = 0. That operation clearly does not overflow, so `V` (overflow) is set to 0.

More information about the *condition flags* in the ARM architecture can be found [here](http://community.arm.com/groups/processors/blog/2010/07/16/condition-codes-1-condition-flags-and-codes).

Comment: One additional point: depending on the disassembler/settings, the Thumb-1 instructions (short, 16-bit encodings for a subset of instructions) may be displayed without the S suffix, even though they, in fact, do update flags. See Table 4-9 [here](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dui0473j/dom1359731157381.html).

Comment: Is it because it is the default behavior of the instruction in thumb mode, or the opcodes are really different but the mnemonic does not show up the difference ?

Comment: The former. In Thumb-1, all ALU instructions set the flags and so I guess the creators dropped the suffix as "unnecessary". With Thumb-2, full equivalence with the ARM set was achieved and you can choose if you want to set flags or not. Thus the move to UAL and explicit S suffix.

Comment: Shouldn't the explanation to `N == 0` be `The result is greater than or equal to 0 ...` ?

Comment: @perror There is another tricky thing about flags which is called flexible second operand: C flag can be updated in some cases even if S suffix does not exist in the command, see http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0489i/CIHDDCIF.html for more details

Comment: @ws Okay, so it seems that these bit-shifts operations do touch the carry flag as well... Thanks for noticing it !